# Trigger Validation on Specific Row using React and Formik

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, formik

I have two "save" buttons which basically do the same thing.
I wanted the other one `onAnotherSubmit` which has a type="button" to trigger the validation.
How do i do it?

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-pike-mp6lqc?file=/src/components/ProductCard/index.js)

```
   const anotherSubmit = ({ values, errors, validateForm }) => {
    validateForm().then((validation) => formik.setTouched(validation));
    console.log(errors);
    console.log(values);
    if (!errors) {
      console.log("yes submit");
    }
  };


      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        type="button"
        onClick={() => anotherSubmit(formik)}
      >
        Save with type="button"
      </Button>
```

Comment: I have no idea how to do it but hopefully this could be helpful.https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#manually-triggering-validation

Comment: @riskylast. Updated my codesandbox but it seems some delay when there's no error in if statement. Probably there's better way to do it.